# How to add Mac's command special sign into a markdown document using HTML tags?

Tags: macos, html, markdown

I have a `markdown` document with the following line:

> Press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>

In HTML:

```
Press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd>
```

Instead of <kbd>CMD</kbd> I want to add the special Mac glyph.

How to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're looking for the `PLACE OF INTEREST SIGN`, ⌘.

[image]

The HTML entity for it is `&#8984;`.

---

Note that you can press <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to bring up the Character Viewer in most applications (or go to *Edit » Special Characters*). Here, you can add various characters to your favorite list for later use.

Some examples for characters often used in Mac keyboard shortcuts:

- ⌥ – Alt / Option
- ⌃ – Control
- ⇧ – Shift
- ⌫ / ⌦ – Backward / Forward delete

Comment: Is there a shortcut for this character other then going into **Character Viewer** and selecting from there?

Comment: How can I add new various characters into Character Viewer ?.I am using `vim` editor. The reason is that I do not have this special character in the favourited list and at all there...

Comment: Character Viewer can show all characters on your system—you cannot add new ones to it. You can only change your favorites. Click the small preferences sign and make sure to select all lists that you want. You can then search for characters, and if you select one, click the *Add to Favorites* button on the right.

Comment: Is there a list of these entities? How does this look on a PC?

Comment: @Shanimal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters — the specific rendering depends on your OS, of course.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see &#8984; searching that link, but i found this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55727/where-can-i-find-the-unicode-symbols-for-mac-functional-keys-command-shift-e Hopefully its useful.

Comment: @Shanimal Ah, I didn't know that with "*these* entities", you were referring to characters that are primarily used on Macs. Glad you found something!